# WPF: Component interferes with hotkeys

Tags: c#, wpf, hotkeys

I have embedded Acrobat Reader in my WPF application, and I have defined several hotkeys that I want to do some work, but the hotkeys only work when I'm inside textboxes and similar. I have discovered that this must be because Adobe Acrobat Reader gets the hotkeys before I do, because if I map ctrl-shift-s to a function, when I press it inside a textbox my function is called, but if the focus is not in a textbox, Adobe's save function is called.

How can I make sure my the hotkeys defined for MainWindow are the ones that are executed, and not that of Acrobat Reader or anything else?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like keyboard focus in your application defaults to the embedded Acrobat Reader, so when your main window gets a key press it gives them to Reader in preference of anything else, including its own menu commands.

That's somewhat difficult since you likely *want* Reader to receive focus and handle its keyboard shortcuts -- just not the ones that are also defined by your main window.

Try overriding OnKeyDown in your MainWindow class and see if Ctrl+Shift+S arrives there. If it does, respond by directly calling your appropriate command event handler, and set Handled to true on the event argument to prevent MainWindow from sending that key anywhere else.

Comment: That sounds interesting. I don't need the keyboard shortcuts in Acrobat Reader, I'll only be using it to look at a single page and possibly copy out some OCR'ed text. (ok, so I guess I'll need ctrl-c, but that's it :-) )  Is there any way to let my application handle the keyboard first, getting keyboard focus and then leaving it for Acrobat if I don't respond? Thanks for the tip on OnKeyDown, I'll use that to check. :-)

Comment: Ultimately, the user of your application controls keyboard focus, and Reader must receive focus for text selection & copying, so I don't think trying to wrestle focus away from Reader is going to work. But in the OnKeyDown override, you can simply set Handled to true on the event argument for any keyboard shortcut you don't want Reader to handle.